# Turn java Servlet Map.toString response to json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, servlets

I'm having trouble turning my servlet `response` to a valid `Json`, here is the returned `String`:

```
"key:gt,value:true, key:ht,value:false"
```

In js console the output is `key:gt,value:true, key:ht,value:false` (without `""`).
Tried `Regex` and some other js function but I'm a backend guy.
I had already handled Line Breaks using `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")`
I can't use other java libs like Gson, need a pure js or angular solution.
This should be valid for `ng-repeat` as well.
This is as far as I can get:
used `split(" ")`, `substring(1,length-1)` and added `'{' + '}'`:

```
["{key:gt,value:true}","{key:gt,value:true}"...]
```

But still not a vaild Json.

Thank you all.

Comment: I can not use other libs(like Gson or org) in my server(organization reasons), need some js.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant solution to your problem. Ideally you should return a JSON response from your server (but I think you know that).

Having said that, you said you tried using a regexp with little success. Here's a possible solution:

```
//Assuming your processed input string looks like this: key:gt,value:true";
var regexp = /key:([^,]+),value:([^,]+)/g;
var match = regexp.exec(myString);
```

The "key" value will be stored in `match[1]` and the "value" value in `match[2]`. This solution is only good for string values (you'd have to match and parse other values back manually), and won't be able to cope with nested elements. 
If I where you though, I'd either try and find a way to produce JSON on your server using a lib (preferable) or manually (error prone) and use `JSON.parse()` to get the values.